# Find sum of neighbors 2d array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, time-complexity, big-o, neighbours

Write a function where the function takes in 2 inputs a matrix, for example 2-dimensional array, and indices: for example [row, col]
This function should return the sum of all the second inputs neighbors (up, down, left, right, diagonals)

What will be the complexity of the code below.I think time complexity will be O(row*cols) and constant space O(1).
Kindly provide thoughts.

```
function validateMatrixCoordinates(arrayMatrix, x, y) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arrayMatrix) || !Array.isArray(arrayMatrix[0])) {
    console.log("arrayMatrix is not a matrix of arrays");
    return false;
  }
  if (!Number.isInteger(x) || !Number.isInteger(y)) {
    console.log("Index is not an Integer");
    return false;
  }
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > arrayMatrix.length - 1 || y > arrayMatrix[0].length - 1) {
    console.log("Index is Out Of Bounds");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function sumMatrixNeighbors(arrayMatrix, x, y) {
  let rowLimit = arrayMatrix.length - 1;
  let columnLimit = arrayMatrix[0].length - 1;
  let sum = 0;

  if (!validateMatrixCoordinates(arrayMatrix, x, y)) {
    return;
  }
  for (let i = Math.max(0, x - 1); i <= Math.min(x + 1, rowLimit); i++) {
    for (let j = Math.max(0, y - 1); j <= Math.min(y + 1, columnLimit); j++) {
      if ((x !== i || y !== j) && Number.isInteger(arrayMatrix[i][j])) {
        sum += arrayMatrix[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

let input = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];

console.log('Result for [2, 1]: ' + sumMatrixNeighbors(input, 2, 1));
console.log('Result for [0, 0]: ' + sumMatrixNeighbors(input, 0, 0));
console.log('Result for ["a", 0]: ' + sumMatrixNeighbors(input, "a", 0));
console.log('Result for [1, -1]: ' + sumMatrixNeighbors(input, 1, -1));
console.log('Result for [1, 4]: ' + sumMatrixNeighbors(input, 1, 4));
```

Comment: If the code works there's nothing to fix. Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where working code is refactored.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first post. Apologies!!

Comment: Editing the same post to avoid duplicates.